# How does DoubleQuotedScalarString apply to a CommentedMap

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

When I use the `CommentedMap` of the `ruamel.yaml` library to store ordered dictionaries, I need to put the contents of the CommentedMap **in the value of the dictionary as a string**, but when I manipulate it with `DoubleQuotedScalarString`, the output comes with unneeded fields like `ordereddict`.

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap      # CommentedMap用于解决ordereddict数据dump时带"!omap"这样的字段
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString,DoubleQuotedScalarString
from pathlib import Path
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=6, offset=4)

file_yml = CommentedMap()
test = CommentedMap()
test['test1'] = "test1"
test['test2'] = "test2"
file_yml["test"] = DoubleQuotedScalarString(test)

path = Path("./test.yaml")
yaml.dump(file_yml, path)
```

the result as follow

```
test: "ordereddict([('test1', 'test1'), ('test2', 'test2')])"
```

I'm looking forward to is the result of the **test, "{' test1 ': 'test1', 'test2': 'test2'}"**

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't apply `DoubleQuotedScalarString` to a `CommentedMap`. The only thing the former is useful for is to make sure individual strings, that may part of a mapping or sequence, do get double quotes. By applying it the `CommentedMap`, you convert the whole into a string and that `CommntedMap` is an `ordereddict`.

You should probably just do:

```
test = dict()
```

and then later on:

```
file_yml["test"] = str(test)
```

On modern versions of Python this will preserve the key insertion order, and the quotes should be added as a scalar cannot start with `{` without being quoted automatically.

If test needs to be a `CommentedMap` before dumping it as a string, then cast it to a dict:

```
test = CommentedMap()
.....
file_yaml["test"] = str(dict(test))
```

Comment: Sorry, because of the previous work, `file_yml` must be of type `CommentedMap`, but I expect to be able to transfer it from the above case, and I try to cast through `str()`, but still carry `ordereddict`.
It is expected that there will be an appropriate way to implement the above requirements.

Comment: Sorry I misread. `file_yaml` is irrelevant, `test` should be a dict, or cast to a dict. I updated my answer.